# Please explain the -f option in pgrep

Tags: command-line, process, grep, command

man `pgrep` says the following about `-f` option:

```
   -f     The  pattern  is normally only matched against the process name.
              When -f is set, the full command line is used.
```

What does it mean to say the full command line is used?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It means that without `-f`, `pgrep` only searches for the provided regexp in the command names, while with `-f` it searches it in their arguments (where the first argument (`argv[0]`) is not necessarily the same as the command name).

```
$ sleep 2000 &
[1] 15768
$ pgrep 2000
$ pgrep -f 2000
15768
```

And if we cause `argv[0]` to be different from the command name (on Linux as seen in `/proc/$pid/stat`) as when using `zsh`'s `ARGV0`:

```
$ ARGV0=foo sleep 2000 &
[2] 15881
$ ps -fp $!
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
chazelas 15881 13126  0 19:55 pts/1    00:00:00 foo 2000
$ ps -o comm= $!
sleep
$ awk '{print $2}' /proc/$!/stat
(sleep)
$ pgrep foo
$ pgrep sleep
15881
$ pgrep -f sleep
$ pgrep -f foo
15881
```

There's a lot of potential confusion regarding process name on Unix and Linux. There are 3 attributes of a process that could claim being the process name:

- The base name of the executable that was passed to the last execve(2) system call that the process made. On Linux, that is used to initialise the process name, as reported by `ps` or found in `/proc/$pid/stat`. However, it should be noted that on Linux, it can be changed using `prctl(PR_SET_NAME...)`.
- any path to the executable that is currently `mmap`ed for execution in the process and preferably the path as it was invoked (for scripts, that would be the path provided in the shebang line for instance). On Linux, you can get it with a `readlink` or `/proc/$pid/exe`. That one, you can't change without calling another `execve` (though you could in theory load a new executable in memory and execute its code without calling `execve`, see for instance some attempts at a [user land execve](http://plash.beasts.org/wiki/UserModeExec)).
- The first argument passed along the execve system call. By convention, that argument is meant to tell the application its name to let it know how to behave accordingly so is often what is meant by the process name. On Linux, it can be found in `/proc/$pid/cmdline`, but a process can also change it by modifying the memory pointed to by `argv[0]`.

It should also be noted that there's a lot of variation among the difference Unices.

Comment: you wrote "(where the first argument (argv[0]) is not necessarily the same as the command name)." First argument is ways different than the command name right ? For example when you did sleep 2000 & , "2000" is the first argument to the command "sleep ". Am I missing something fundamental here ?

Comment: what does the " $!" part in  ps -fp $! indicate ?

Comment: @Geek, depends how you want to count. In "sleep 2000", you call "/usr/bin/sleep" with two arguments: "sleep" and "2000". Now, you may want to call them the 1st and 2nd arguments or the 0th and 1st arguments since the 0th one is treated specially by most applications (and not as much as an argument they should act upon, but one that tells them their name). `$!` is the PID of the last command run in background.

Answer (score -3):

when you `ps -f` you will see more details about the processes including the associated commands and process information. When you `pgrep -f` it will search that additional information to match your query as opposed to what is displayed when you just use `ps` or `ps -e`